# Media Module for Python 3.2

Tags: image, module, python-3.x

I'm taking an introductory computer science course this semester and my professor has us using Practical Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science Using Python for our textbook. I'm working through the 4th chapter on modules and I've run into a bit of a snag. The book uses a module named 'media' for working with images, but it runs in Python 2.5. I was wondering if there is an equivalent module for 3.2. I've been looking around and so far haven't found one, but I'm not sure I've looked in the right places. Thanks!

Comment: If the book is written for Python 2.5, the best is to use 2.5 to go through it.

Comment: True, but my professor expects all of our code to be in Python 3.

Comment: So your professor gives you a book for Python 2.5 and expects code for Python 3? Either he has a very high opinion of you, or he doesn't know what he is doing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your codes this way(Python-3):

```
import dir1.dir2.media.py
```

The dir1.dir2 is the path where your media.py located (BTW: You can get the path of media.py by using the software: *everything* in Windows),

e.g.Your media.py is in the path: D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\resources\media.py. Then you can use the subdirectory under site_packages file:

```
import twilio.rest.resources.media
```

Hope this will help.